# Chaining two parentheses together using $ operator

Tags: haskell, syntax, function-composition, dollar-sign

I have this function:

```
min (max 10 20) (max 30 40)
```

I can rewrite this as:

```
min (max 10 20) $ max 30 40
```

But is there also a way to resolve these last parentheses?

Not as if this wasn't good enough, but I just can't let the thought go, that there must be some way to do this...

Comment: `let (&) :: (a -> b) -> a -> b; (&) = ($); infixl 0 &; min & max 1 2 & max 3 4`

Comment: `(&)` is usually used for `flip ($)`, and I'd make the precedence 1, but the principle is nice.

Comment: How can you look up the definition of functions like `$` or `.` in `ghci`? Writing `:t $` will just give an input error.

Comment: You use `:info $` in GHCi.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would be nice to be able to write:

```hs
min $ max 10 20 $ max 30 40
```

However, this wouldn't work because `$` is right associative:

```hs
Prelude> :info $
($) :: (a -> b) -> a -> b   -- Defined in ‘GHC.Base’
infixr 0 $
```

Hence, the expression is disambiguated as:

```hs
min ((max 10 20) max 30 40)
```

Indeed, it would make more sense for `$` to be left associative. However, we can't simply make `$` left associative because it might break existing code. Nevertheless, you could define a new operator:

```hs
infixl 0 %

(%) :: (a -> b) -> a -> b
f % x = f x

main = print (min % max 10 20 % max 30 40)
```

The `%` symbol is right next to the `$` symbol on a US keyboard.

Answer (score 5):

You're looking for

```
max 10 20 `min` max 30 40
```

Comment: While this is an elegant solution, it doesn't work in the general case. For example, this method can't be used when there is are more than two arguments. It can't be used when the function to be applied is not directly referenced either.

Comment: @AaditMShah right. However, in these cases, it is probably best to _use_ parens, or named subexpressions in a `where` binding. For simple cases like this, the infix trick works great.

Comment: @leftaroundabout In these cases, it's best to simply write `min (max 10 20) (max 30 40)`. Parentheses aren't bad. In fact, I've been trying to avoid `$` as much as possible for the sake of consistency. It doesn't really help make things clearer. Any benefit of using infix `$` is, in my humble opinion, purely psychological. The only real use case for `$` is right sections (e.g. `map ($ 2) [odd, even]`).

Comment: @AaditMShah: I wouldn't quite agree with _that_. Sure, there's no objective benefit if you use `$` to get rid of a single pair of parens, but it can make code tremendously more readable if you use it to reduce a quadruply-nested bracket construct to just a doubly-nested one. Though again, one should of course also consider local named variables in such a case.