# confused about composite function in haskell

Tags: haskell

```
let f = show.sum.map read.words
f "1 2"
```

It work.

```
show.sum.map read.words "1 2"
```

I get errors:

```
<interactive>:19:19:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘a -> [String]’
                with actual type ‘[String]’
    Relevant bindings include
      it :: a -> String (bound at <interactive>:19:1)
    Possible cause: ‘words’ is applied to too many arguments
    In the second argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘words "1 2"’
    In the second argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘map read . words "1 2"’
Prelude> :t show.sum.map
show.sum.map
  :: (Num [b], Show b, Foldable ((->) [a])) => (a -> b) -> String
Prelude> show.sum.map read.words "1 2"

    <interactive>:21:19:
        Couldn't match expected type ‘a -> [String]’
                    with actual type ‘[String]’
        Relevant bindings include
          it :: a -> String (bound at <interactive>:21:1)
        Possible cause: ‘words’ is applied to too many arguments
        In the second argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘words "1 2"’
        In the second argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘map read . words "1 2"’
    Prelude>
```

I want to know why? (show.sum.map read.words) "1 2" can also work.

Comment: Incidentally, it's usual to write `foo . bar . baz` (with spaces) rather than `foo.bar.baz`, to emphasize that it's function composition, not a qualified name (e.g., `Data.List.sort` or something).

Answer (score 8):

The issue is that application binds more tightly than application which in fact has the highest precedence of any Haskell operator. This means that your code actually parses

```
 show.sum.map read.(words "1 2")
```

which doesn't type check because `words "1 2"` has the type `String`, not something that can be composed with `.`. In order to fix this you can use the `$` operator which is specifically designed to behave as application but which the lowest precedence instead of the highest.

```
 show.sum.map read.words $ "1 2"
```

will work as intended because it has the correct association. This is in general why you'll see the pattern in Haskell code (well at least my Haskell code) of `foo . bar . baz $ quux` quite frequently.

Comment: Also worth pointing out that you can simply specify the precedence explicitly: `(show . sum . map read . words) "1 2"`. Using `$` is definitely a more common approach, but telling a beginner *only* about that version inevitably leads to a later question like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36682882/chaining-two-parentheses-together-using-operator/36682941 because they think that `$` is The Way to override operator precedence.

Comment: Thanks for your help.